# How to change the position of weights of nodes in a digraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, draw

I used the following latex code to draw [this digraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrCsi.jpg).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       [> = stealth,
        shorten > = 1pt, 
        auto,
        node distance = 2cm, 
        thick ]

    \tikzstyle{every state}=[
        draw = black,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 2mm]

    \node[state] (v1) {$v_1$};
     \node[state] (v2) [right of=v1] {$v_2$};
       \path[->] (v2) edge node {$1$} (v1);
      \node[state] (v3) [right of=v2] {$v_3$};
        \path[->] (v3) edge node {$1$} (v2);
      \node[state] (v4) [right of=v3] {$v_4$};
       \path[->] (v4) edge node {$1$} (v3);
     \node[state] (v5) [right of=v4] {$v_5$};
       \path[->] (v5) edge node {$1$} (v4);
     \node[state] (v6) [right of=v5] {$v_6$};
       \path[->] (v6) edge node {$1$} (v5);

         \path (v1) edge [loop left] node {$u_1$} (v1);
        \path[->] (v1) edge[bend left=30] node {$u_2$}  (v2);
         \path[->] (v1) edge[bend left=40] node  {$u_3$}  (v3);
          \path[->] (v1) edge[bend left=50] node {$u_4$}  (v4);
           \path[->] (v1) edge[bend left=55] node {$u_5$}  (v5);
            \path[->] (v1) edge[bend left=60] node  {$u_6$}  (v6);

   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

I would greatly appreciate to improve my latex code such that the output of code be similar to the [mentioned digraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrCsi.jpg).
In fact my problems are the size of circles that want to be smaller and the positions of `$u_i$`’s and the loop for the node `v_1`.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use the `quotes` library to make edge labels, because it offers the syntax `(source) edge["label"] (target)` which is shorter than `(source) edge node {label} (target)`. The option to control the position of the label is `pos`; I think `pos=0.8` leads to reasonable output, but you could fiddle with it yourself. I also used a `\foreach` loop to simplify your first bit of code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata,quotes} % quotes library adds quotes syntax
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       [> = stealth,
        shorten > = 1pt, 
        auto,
        node distance = 2cm, 
        thick , 
        % automatically put nodes in math mode:
        execute at begin node=$,execute at end node=$ 
]

    \tikzset{every state/.style={thick,minimum size = 2mm}}

  \node[state] (v1) {v_1};  
    % Use a loop to make the states. \lastn holds \n minus 1 
  \foreach \n[remember=\n as \lastn (initially 1)] in {2,...,6}{
         \node[state] (v\n) [right of=v\lastn] {v_\n};
         \draw[<-] (v\lastn) edge["1"'] (v\n);
    }


        \draw (v1) edge [loop left,"u_1"]  (v1);
  % Put all the rest of the labels 8/10ths of the way across the edge
    \tikzset{every edge quotes/.style={pos=0.8}}
        \draw[->] (v1) edge[bend left=30,"u_2" ] (v2);
        \draw[->] (v1) edge[bend left=40,"u_3"]  (v3);
        \draw[->] (v1) edge[bend left=50,"u_4"]  (v4);
        \draw[->] (v1) edge[bend left=55,"u_5"]  (v5);
        \draw[->] (v1) edge[bend left=60,"u_6"] (v6);

   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

slightly modified nice [Hood Chatham](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23866/hood-chatham)'s answer (most changes are off-topic):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, quotes} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       [shorten > = 1pt,
        auto,
        node distance = 2cm,
        thick ,
        execute at begin node=$,execute at end node=$,% put nodes in math mode ...
    every state/.style = {thick, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=1mm},  % <--- added
    every  edge/.style = {draw, -stealth},                          % <--- added 
        ]
  \node[state] (v1) {v_1};
  % Use a loop to make the states. \lastn holds \n minus 1
  \foreach \n [remember=\n as \lastn (initially 1)] in {2,...,6}%
  {
    \node[state] (v\n) [right of=v\lastn] {v_\n};
    \draw (v\n) edge["1"] (v\lastn);                                % <--- changed
  }
  \draw (v1) edge [out=135, in=225, looseness=8, "u_1" ']  (v1);    % <--- added
  % bended edges
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \a using 30 + 6*\i] in {2,...,6}      % <--- added
  \draw (v1) edge[inner sep=1pt, pos=0.75, bend left=\a, "u_\i"]    (v\i);  % <--- modified
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**

if i correctly understood your comment, you like change the first solution to something like this:

[image]

in *mwe* below are changes in comparison of above *mwe* indicated with `% <--- new`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, 
                chains,                                             % <--- new
                positioning,                                        % <--- new
                quotes} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       [shorten > = 1pt,
        auto,
        node distance = 2cm,
        start chain = grow right,                                   % <--- new
        thick ,
        execute at begin node=$,execute at end node=$,% put nodes in math mode ...
    every state/.style = {thick, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=1mm,
                          on chain},                                % <--- new
    every  edge/.style = {draw, -stealth},                          
        ]
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {1,2,3,n}                        % <--- changed
    \node (v\j) [state, on chain] {v_\i};                           % <--- changed
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {2,...,4}                        % <--- new
  {
    \ifnum\i<4                                                      % <--- new
    \draw (v\i) edge["1"] (v\j);                                    % <--- new
    \else                                                           % <--- new
    \draw[-, very thick, dotted,                                    % <--- new
          shorten <=1mm] (v\i) -- (v\j);                            % <--- new
    \fi                                                             % <--- new
  }
  % bended edges
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 2,                                     % <--- new
               evaluate=\j as \a using 30 + 6*\j] in {2,3,n}        % <--- changed
  \draw (v1) edge[inner sep=1pt, pos=0.75, bend left=\a, "u_\i"]    (v\j);  
  \draw (v1) edge [out=135, in=225, looseness=8, "u_1" ']  (v1);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice code. I have a question. If I had n nodes v_1, v_2, ..., v_n, How to use the command \cdots between the diagram. Thank you

Comment: @Amin235, see if added solution (in addendum) is what you looking for.

Comment: What a nice and efficient LaTex code you have written. Really  Really thanks for your answer.